# Anyone know of any OpenGL apps in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, opengl, source-code, open-source

im trying to find some apps in ubuntu that use opengl mostly. so i can read and learn from the source code. 
i know of Blender, but i looking for a smaller program.
google just give me installation of opengl, nothing else.

any suggestions would be help all of those looking for the same.
thanks
Alex

Answer (score 3):

The package `mesa-utils` contains some simple OpenGL programs like `glxgears`.

Running

```
apt-cache rdepends libgl1-mesa-glxq
```

on the command line will give you a list of more packages using OpenGL